# SQL 2 columns in different tables as distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

This has been resolved, I needed to join 4 tables in SQL with 2 columns in different tables as distinct.  I would consistently get duplicate rows until now.

I have 4 Tables that I am trying to join with 1 query.

I need to create a report that looks like:

`quoteid | dateEntered | insuredName | admin initials | quoteType | status | last note usertype`

```
Select quoteID,insuredFirstName,insuredLastName,quoteType,status, firstname, lastname, adminInitial, userType
from (SELECT Row_Number() Over(Partition by A.quoteid  order by A.quoteid ) as Row , A.quoteID, A.insuredFirstName, A.insuredLastName, A.quoteType, A.status, B.firstName, B.lastName, left(C.firstName,1) + left(C.lastName,1) as adminInitial, D.userType
    FROM quotes A
    INNER JOIN tbl_agents B
    ON A.createUserID = B.AgentNumber
    INNER JOIN tbl_admins C
    ON A.assignedID = C.ID
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT 
            quoteID, userType
            FROM quote_notes) D
            ON A.quoteID = D.quoteID) as t where row=1
```

Comment: Distinct will prevent duplicates!

Comment: @user1848739 Using `distinct` in that case is hiding the problem.

Comment: Yeah it seems that Distinct is only removing some duplicates, but since there are 4 tables perhaps its only being applied to certain ones?

Comment: SELECT  DISTINCT quoteID, userType FROM quote_notes run and check it return didtinct id i dont think so...cz two column in distinct

Comment: @AmitSingh : It works there - wow such a simple mistake on my part, I guess you just start to go cross-eyed after a while

Comment: run it seperately and see it returns distinct qoute id or not....

Comment: @AmitSingh ,  I ran it seperately and it worked.  I applied it to my query and it works well too.  Only problem now is that it states "Invalid column name 'userType'" because I am referring to D.usertype in the main select statement.  How do I include the usertype as well?

Comment: show yuor updated query and what rdbms you are using now

Comment: what rdbms you are using?

Comment: @evade: If you add a URL for the image, other users can add it to the question for you.

Comment: @AmitSingh am using SQL Server 2008 - both you and dmg helped solve this one, I updated the question with the answer.  Thank you

Comment: welcome @evade can you post your updated query,,,,

Comment: are sure it works distinct will apply on all column set

Comment: i dont think it works...and if it works thanit not reliabel

Comment: @AmitSingh you're right, it does apply to all tables, any ideas?

Comment: @evade which column you want to be distinct i mean according to which column you want to distinct record..

Comment: @AmitSingh I actually need it to be disctinct on 2 columns, is that possible?  Perhaps the query needs to be reworked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this use `Row_Number()` using `Partition by` like this...

```
  Select quoteID,insuredFirstName,insuredLastName,quoteType,status from (SELECT Row_Number() Over(Partition by quoteid ,Name1  order by quoteid ) as Row , A.quoteID, A.insuredFirstName, A.insuredLastName, A.quoteType, A.status, B.firstName, B.lastName, left(C.firstName,1) + left(C.lastName,1) as adminInitial, D.userType
        FROM quotes A
        INNER JOIN tbl_agents B
        ON A.createUserID = B.AgentNumber
        INNER JOIN tbl_admins C
        ON A.assignedID = C.ID
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT 
                quoteID, userType
                FROM quote_notes) D
                ON A.quoteID = D.quoteID) as t where row=1
```

Comment: I will give this a shot when Im back in the office on Monday ~ thanks

Comment: Amit, wow.. thank you.  The whole nested selects and joins are new to me.  Thank you for putting this into perspective.

Comment: if I wanted to add a where filter to the whole query, where would I place that?  It seems wherever I place 'where quoteid = 'xxxxxxx' it causes a syntax error.

Comment: just append after where i write row=1 like where row=1 and t.qouteid=123

Comment: one last thing, I am noticing that it is leaving out some rows.  Perhaps ones without an entry in the notes table or another table?  -  Some quotes may not have any notes yet

Comment: @evade sorry i can not understand

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the **`DISTINCT`** from the `inner` query to the `outside` query.

Comment: Moving distinct outside the query worked as well.  Thank you every one! I updated the post to state the answer I used.

Comment: This got me about halfway, the accepted answer showed the right result